# Mostrar mi ubicación en map fragment - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, map, supportmapfragment

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual me muestra marcadores en el mapa, lo que quiero es que al abrir el mapa me haga un zoom en la ubicación exacta de donde me encuentro, he buscado ejemplos pero no logro dar con la respuesta, gracias  de antemano.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fm_buscarestacionamientos);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Buscar Estacionamiento");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap));
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap = googleMap;


    //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    String url = "http://www.app.transportessalgado.cl/obtenercoordenadas.php";
    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));

        location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tienda = data.getJSONObject(i);

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(data.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("latitud"),
                            data.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("longitud")))
                    .title(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_estacionamiento")).flat(true)
                    .snippet(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_estacionamiento"))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.automovil))));

                    final String rutadministrador= data.getJSONObject(i).getString("usuario_rut_administrador");

                marker.showInfoWindow();
                idmarcador=marker.getId();
                mHashMap.put(i,marker);

                final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Location = location;

            googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                        String idmarker= marker.getId();
                       String titulo=marker.getTitle();
                       String idestacionamiento=marker.getSnippet();


                       //float rutadministrador=marker.getAlpha();
                       //String rutadmi=String.valueOf(rutadministrador);

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmarReserva.class);

                        i.putExtra("id_estacionamiento",idestacionamiento );
                        i.putExtra("usuario_rut_administrador", rutadministrador);
                        i.putExtra("nombre_estacionamiento", titulo);
                        Log.e("Informacion_enviada", valueOf(Location));
                        startActivity(i);


                        }
                        }
                );

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Y aquí una imagen de como se visualiza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Al obtener el `MapFragment` habilita obtener tu geo localización:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap));
//Habilita geo loalización.
mapFragment.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

y usa `OnMyLocationChangeListener` para obtener la posición actual

```
    if (mapFragment!= null) {

        mapFragment.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location loc) {

                //*Agrega marcador de posición actual a MapFragment.
                mapFragment.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude())).title("Hey FEFE, this is my current position!!!"));
            }
        });

    }
```

Este método funciona pero va a ser obsoleto,  por lo que te sugiero revises acerca de [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)  y [Google Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro)

Aquí un completo tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.